# Problems in $\textbf{DSPACE}(\log^2 n)$

Tags: complexity-theory

Let some problem $P$ is in $\textbf{DSPACE}(\log^2 n)$  and $Q$ is a problem in $\textbf{DSPACE}(\log n)$. I can claim that $P$ is polynomial time solvable as number of turing machine configurations for problem $Q$ is polynomial many.

**Question :**  Can I say that $\textbf{DSPACE}(\log^2 n)$ is in polynomial time complexity class?

Answer (score 1):

There are about $2^{\log^2n}$ possible configurations, and $2^{\log^2n} = n^{\log n}$, which is not polynomial (it's "quasipolynomial"). So, no, you can't claim that $\mathrm{DSPACE}[\log^2 n]\subseteq \mathrm{P}$.